# In a UICollectionView, how can I get my cells to autolayout BEFORE they appear on screen?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView with self sizing cells. When I scroll through the collection I can see the cells resizing themselves at the bottom of the screen.

Is there a way I can get the cells to resize themselves before the appear?

I am using flow layout and my cells contain just 3 labels. I am also using estimatedItemSize.